# What is the safest way to fake a reference by temporarily pretending it's `'static`?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'm in a not-so-great situation and have to fake a lifetime. It looks a little bit like this:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    cr: &'a mut char,
}

fn foo<D, F>(data: D, f: F) 
where
    D: 'static,     // <-- !!!
    F: FnOnce(D),
{ ... }


let mut c = '⚠';
let bar = Bar { cr: &mut c };
foo(???, |c| /* I need access to a `Bar` here! */);
```

I have to call the strange function `foo`. In the closure I pass to it, I need to get access to a `Bar` (with any lifetime) that was passed through `foo`. (I know in this minimal example I could just access the `bar` directly as closures have access to their environment, but let's pretend that's not possible here.) Unfortunately, `foo` requires `D: 'static`.

Of course, in reality everything is more complicated. I know `Bar` and `foo` don't make too much sense, but this is my attempt at breaking my problem into a minimal example.

---

How do I make this work? I believe it is possible to make this work safely (i.e. without undefined behavior), but I'm sure it requires the `unsafe` keyword.

The basic idea is to cast the `Bar<'not_static>` to a `Bar<'static>` temporarily, then make sure that it does not outlive the original `c`. I want to know how to best do that. My idea was the following:

```
let mut c = '⚠';
let bar = Bar { cr: &mut c };
let bar_static: Arc<Bar<'static>> = unsafe {
    let extended = mem::transmute::<Bar<'_>, Bar<'static>>(bar);
    Arc::new(extended)
};

foo(bar_static.clone(), |bar| println!("{}", bar.cr));

if Arc::strong_count(&bar_static) != 1 && Arc::weak_count(&bar_static) != 0 {
    eprintln!("bad!");
    std::process::abort();
}
```

The idea is to dynamically check that no references to `c` exist anymore (apart from the one we are holding) after calling `foo`. That should protect against `foo` storing the `data` in a static variable or something like that. I don't expect it, but I rather end the whole process instead of having memory unsafety in my program.

With this, I think, I make sure that the reference (which is incorrectly `'static`) does not outlive the actual data. But:

- Is that reasoning sane? Does it make sense?
- What worries me is that rustc doesn't think `c` is borrowed after the `unsafe` block. I could (in my function) arbitrarily access `c`, although there exists a reference pointing to it. Is that a case of "I'm fine as long as I don't actually access `c`"? Or rather one of those "immediate UB" cases?
- Is `mem::transmute` the right tool for the job or should I use pointer casts or something else?
- Any better ideas?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to change `foo` to include a non-static lifetime? `fn foo<'a, D: 'a, F>` ?

Comment: I don't quite see how could you possibly safely pretend `bar` is static when it's absolutely not

Comment: @ToninGuy3n Nop, unfortunately not. `foo` is fixed basically. And Alexey Larionov: I'm fairly sure this is actually allowed by Rust. I know of a few libraries where this is necessary and done (e.g. `crossbeam::scope`). But sure, if I'm wrong and you can point me to some docs saying that lifetime faking is always immediate UB, then that's an answer, too.

Comment: Calling `transmute` directly is risky, at least I would use a wrapper, like: `unsafe fn extend_lifetime<T>(r: &T) -> &'static T { std::mem::transmute(r) }`.

Comment: Updated my answer for cases where you are unable to alter `foo` or `Bar` (see the last example). `foo` must guarantee completion (may need to use `await`/`join` when dealing with threads/futures).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is no safe way to alter the lifetime of your objects. Lifetimes are compiler guarantees that the value will always live for the duration of its use.

The safest route would be to change `foo` to include the lifetime of `data: D`.

```rust
fn foo<'a, D, F>(data: D, f: F)
where D: 'a,
      F: FnOnce(D),
{
    f(data);
}
```

---

An alternative is to alter `Bar` and how it's used via `Arc<Mutex<char>>` and downgrading it to `Weak<Mutex<char>>`.

```
struct Bar {
    c: Weak<Mutex<char>>,
}

let t = 't';
let t = Arc::new(Mutex::new(t));

let bar = Bar { c: Arc::downgrade(&t) };

foo(bar, |b| {
    if let Some(c) = b.c.upgrade() {
        let mut c = c.lock().unwrap();
        println!("{}", *c);
        *c = 'b';
    }

});
println!("{}", t.lock().unwrap());
```

---

However, if it's not possible for you to change `foo` or `Bar` and you are certain that the referenced object will not be dropped, then you can use [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) to alter the lifetime of your object.

As mentioned in the doc:

> `transmute` is incredibly unsafe. There are a vast number of ways to cause undefined behavior with this function. `transmute` should be the absolute last resort.

```rust
unsafe fn to_static<'a>(r: Bar<'a>) -> Bar<'static> {
    std::mem::transmute::<Bar<'a>, Bar<'static>>(r)
}


let mut t = 't';
let bar = Bar { c: &mut t };

let static_bar = unsafe { to_static(bar) };

foo(static_bar, |b: Bar| {
    println!("{}", b.c);
    *b.c = 'b';
});

println!("{}", t);
```

The example above works because `t` lives within the scope where `foo` is called and we know `t` is static so it's perfectly fine to use. However, if `foo` sends `static_bar` into another thread, and `t` is not static, then the result is undefined behaviour.

If you can guarantee that `foo` will complete before the scope it's called in ends, then you can use `Mutex`'s to do the following.

```rust
let t = 't';
let t = Arc::new(Mutex::new(t));

{ // create scope here

    let mut tlock = t.lock().unwrap(); // MutexGuard<char>
    let t_ref_mut = &mut *tlock;       // get &mut char  -- lifetime of mutex guard
    let bar = Bar { c: t_ref_mut };
    
    let static_bar = unsafe { to_static(bar) };
    
    // foo must be guaranteed to complete before the scope ends.

    foo(static_bar, |b| {
        println!("{}", b.c);
        *b.c = 'b';
    });

} // MutexGuard goes out of scope and lock should be released

// sanity check that lock is released and value is altered
println!("{}", t.lock().unwrap());
```

Full source code can be viewed [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=767e1beea9f2f28f6c645f9b618820cb)

Comment: "However, if foo sends static_bar into another thread, and t is not static, then the result is undefined behaviour." -> Not necessarily, right? It would only be UB if the other thread outlives `t`, correct?

Comment: No. If you can't guarantee that `foo` completes before execution resumes, then it's undefined behaviour, even if it completes before `t` is moved or dropped. See this example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be1098dd2a085e6c483a9c7bbc4b38c3). This is because you've essentially told the compiler you're done borrowing `t` when calling `to_static`.

Comment: Updated the example to show `t` being borrowed again with another `Bar` creation [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=839b0274dbed04da8bcc6211d65ef092)